# getopts when first option is a path in bash

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm having an issue with getopts in a bash script. Basically my script would have to be called with something like:

./myScript /path/to/a/folder -a -b

What I have at the top of my code is this:

```
while getopts ":ab" opt; do
 case $opt in
  a) 
   variable=a
   ;;
  b)    
   variable=b
   ;;
  \?)
   echo "invalid option -$OPTARG"
   exit 0
 esac
done

echo "$variable was chosen"
```

Now, this works as long as I call my script without  /path/to/a/folder…  How can I make it to work with it instead?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Put the path *after* the arguments.

Comment: What is your script doing with `/path/to/a/folder`?

Answer (score 3):

If you *MUST* put a path before the arguments, use a [`shift` command](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) to pop the first positional argument off, and leave the rest for getopts.

```
# Call as ./myScript /path/to/a/folder -a -b

path_argument="$1"
shift   # Shifts away one argument by default

while getopts ":ab" opt; do
 case $opt in
  a) 
   variable=a
   ;;
  b)    
   variable=b
   ;;
  \?)
   echo "invalid option -$OPTARG"
   exit 0
 esac
done

echo "$variable was chosen, path argument was $path_argument"
```

The more-standard answer, as [Etan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) mentioned, is to put the non-option arguments AFTER the options. Prefer this style, as it makes your script more consistent with built-in POSIX option parsing.

```
# Call as ./myScript -a -b /path/to/a/folder 

while getopts ":ab" opt; do
 case $opt in
  a) 
   variable=a
   ;;
  b)    
   variable=b
   ;;
  \?)
   echo "invalid option -$OPTARG"
   exit 0
 esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))  # shifts away every option argument,
                       # leaving your path as $1, and every
                       # positional argument as $@
path_argument="$1"
echo "$variable was chosen, path argument was $path_argument"
```